# Does the rate of expansion of the universe depend on the mass or size of the galaxies?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, space-expansion

Does the rate of expansion of the universe depend on the mass or size of the galaxies? How constant dark energy density affect the massive/lighter galaxies?

Comment: Although the rate of the expansion of space is, unlike the motion of material or energetic objects relative to each other, not necessarily limited by the speed of light, I (a layperson) was surprised to find that its expansion is, actually, only known to occur at a rate of no more than 73 kilometers per second per megaparsec.

Comment: See https://news.umich.edu/scientists-find-first-observational-evidence-linking-black-holes-to-dark-energy/ :  The spatial expansion is sometimes considered to result from DE, which, itself, might result from an avoidance of any singularity by the use of Einstein-Cartan Theory, which assigns a tiny spatial extent (several orders of magnitude greater than the Planck length) to fermions, as discussed in Nikodem Poplawski's cosmological model, which is described since 2010 in many preprints found by his name on ARXIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate of expansion of the universe is given by the Hubble constant

[image]

whereby $\rho$ is the matter density (consisting of baryonic and dark matter) and $\Lambda$ the cosmological constant. The Data we have from the microwave background suggest that the curvature parameter $k=0$. So the size of the galaxies doesn't matter, just the matter density averaged over large scales.

Note that the Hubble constant decreases over time and will reach a constant value asymptotically in the far future which means that then the universe will expand exponentially.

Comment: The late exponential expansion seems consistent with the decrease in the Hubble constant, so, although the physicist (Poplawski) who I've mentioned in my comments has claimed that it will simply expand "indefinitely", I think this answer is  good in the context of GR (as opposed to ECT), altho the question currently lacks a tag for either.

Answer (score 3):

The rate of expansion of the universe depends on the Hubble parameter, which as you can see [from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Matter-dominated_universe_(with_a_cosmological_constant)) depends on the matter content of the universe $\Omega_m$, but not on the mass or size of galaxies.

Within a galaxy (regardless of big/small) it's unlikely dark energy plays a part, because dark energy is too small to overcome gravitational effects within a galaxy.